# C++ Do while loop with if statement issue

Tags: c++

I have a function that will keep request user to input 3 data, and after the data are input, the system will prompt user if they wish to enter another set of input, by reading input from user, and if it is 'Y', the system will prompt again, if it is 'N', then the function will end. But i have problem where if user enter other than 'Y' or 'N', the system should print out a error message and request user to enter the correct choice again.

How do i implement it, as i tried to input a if statement in the do while loop, but it is not working correctly.

```
void addstock()
{
char choice;
char result;

do
{
  // current date/time based on current system
  time_t now = time(0);

  // convert now to string form
  char* dt = ctime(&now);
  // convert now to tm struct for UTC
  tm *gmtm = gmtime(&now);
  dt = asctime(gmtm);


  string itemid;
  string itemdesc;
  int unitprice;
  int balstock;
  string date;


  //getting input from user
  cout<<"";
  getline(cin, itemid);
  cout<<"       Stock ID         :";
  getline(cin, itemid);

  cout<<"       Description      :";
  getline(cin, itemdesc);

  cout<<"       Price       :";
  unitprice = get_Integer();

  date = dt;

  cout<<itemid<<" "<<itemdesc<<" "<<unitprice<<" "<<balstock<<endl;

  cout <<"Testing time is " <<date<<endl;    
  //storing to array
  int i = getstockpilesize();
  stockpile[i].itemid = itemid;
  stockpile[i].itemdesc = itemdesc;
  stockpile[i].unitprice = unitprice;
  stockpile[i].date = date;    
  writeUserDatabase(); //update stockdatabasefile
  cout<<"       \E[1;29mStock ID "<<itemid<<" added...\E[0m"<<endl;
  cout << "Do you want to key in another item (Y/N)" << endl;
  cin >> choice;
  result = toupper(choice);
  cout << "1: " << result <<endl;

  if (result !='Y' || result !='N')
  {
     cout << "Invalid choice, please enter again!" << endl;
     cin >> choice;
     choice = topper(choice);

  }


  }
  while(result =='Y');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Y/N answer handling should be a do-while of it own. Your solution only works for one wrong input - the code in `if{}` never repeats, even if the input is wrong repeatedly.

So you need to make sure the input and its handling is repeated until a correct input is available:

```
do
{
  cin >> choice;
  result = toupper(choice);
  cout << "1: " << result <<endl;

  if (result !='Y' && result !='N')
  {
     cout << "Invalid choice, please enter again!" << endl;
  }
}
while (result != 'Y' && result != 'N');
```

Furthemore, your if() statement is wrong, as it will always be true. I've changed that too.

Answer (score 1):

Turn that

```
if (result !='Y' || result !='N')
```

into

```
while (result !='Y' && result !='N')
```

and your program will keep asking the user as long `result` is neither 'Y' nor 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

Just before ending `if (result !='Y' || result !='N')` if condition, you should say continue like:

```
 if (result !='Y' && result !='N') {
      ...
      continue;//so it asks again user instead of checking condition for just 'Y'
 }
```

Comment: The biggest problem is that the condition `(result !='Y' || result !='N')` is always true.

Comment: i'm quite new to C++ programming. i have tried to input the continue; when the system prompt me if i wish to enter another input, i enter 'g', it will prompt me the error message and ask the the input , but when it read my next input which is 'h', it just jump out of the function call.